# No new window created when running turtle code

Tags: turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am new to python and I am currently using pycharm. I just found out about turtle and thought it was going to be fun to watch YouTube tutorials and make a really easy game so i copied all the code and turns out all that's written is:

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

All the programmers have a new window popping up even with a code like:

```
import turtle

turtle.done()
```

(of course it is a blank window)

but I just wanted to ask if i did anything wrong or if there was something to do in order to make tabs appear.

Comment: Please edit your question to include code. Right now we have no idea what your program is going to be doing or not doing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try defining a `main()` function, and use it in a `if __name__ == '__main__'` statement:

```
import turtle

def main():
    turtle.done()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: it actually worked thank you i don't know why it didn't want to work